# Passing Jenkins classpath via gradle plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have a groovy script with objects which runs in my Jenkins script window.  This script references my Jenkins instance and creates new Jenkins branch jobs.

The script runs in the the Jenkins script window. Now I have a requirement to use Jenkins Gradle plugin to execute the script. The groovy plugin works, but as I said the requirement is to accomplish this via the gradle plugin.

I've tried Gradle task type JavaExec, which forks a new JVM and I lose access to my Jenkins instance. I also tried Groovy `evaluate(File file)` method but classpath reference to Jenkins classes are lost.

```
// FAILS: forks a new JVM that does not have access to Jenkins object graph
task runCreateBranchJobs(type: JavaExec) {
    description 'Create Branch Jobs in Jenkins'
    main = 'createBranchJobs'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

// FAILS: has no knowledge of Jenkins classes, even when evaluated in Jenkins job
task runCreateBranchJobsInSameProcess {
    doLast {
        evaluate(new   File("${projectDir}/src/main/groovy/createBranchJobs.groovy"))
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to run the groovy script within the context of the Jenkins Job while successfully passing the classpath using the gradle plugin?